# load a local javascript into a webview?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to load a local javascript into a react native webview
but it seems that these changes that I want to make on the page are not taken effect, I think that there is some issues in the syntax , could you please correct my syntax

```
 let injec= "document.querySelector('.para').style.color='blue';";
  injec += "document.querySelector('#dicc').style.display='none';";
       const test = "document.querySelectorAll('label');";
      let labels = "Array.from(test) labels.forEach(function(lab) { lab.style.color = 'blue'});";
      injec += labels;

  <WebView
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
    style={webView}
    renderError={this.handleRenderError}
    onError={this.handleRenderError}
    injectedJavaScript= {injec}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using webview like this and it works perfect for me. Try

```
...
render(){
...
 const injectJS = "My_Js_Code";

return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView style={styles.webView}
          source={{uri: 'https://example.com/'}}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          injectedJavaScript={injectJS}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

...
```

Comment: the problem is in the content of Injected javascript , syntax is not correct , may be single quotes is missing or .. i dont know still testing

Comment: There are online tools for debug javascript code. Try them